# Procedures and functions not found while executing GDL commands

Tags: procedure, idl-programming-language, gdl

I've installed GDL recently, since I don't have a license for IDL.

I was trying to run and IDL (.pro) script for simulate exoplanetary transit (with exomoon) and I got some issues:

```
GDL> .reset_session                                                 

(gdl:16530): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
GDL> 
GDL> restore, 'paramk63.save', /v
% Procedure not found: RESTORE
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$          
GDL> 
GDL> Per = PER
GDL> ap = A
% Variable is undefined: A
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$          
GDL> Rplan = RP
% Variable is undefined: RP
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$          
GDL> inc = INC
GDL> Pm = 1
GDL> Rmoon = 0.03
GDL> dmoon = 4.0
GDL> tetam0 = 0.0
GDL> dt = 1.0
GDL> wl = WL
GDL> 
GDL> eclipse_moon,Per,ap,Rplan,inc,Pm,Rmoon,dmoon,tetam0,dt,wl,/plot
% Compiled module: ECLIPSE_MOON.
% ECLIPSE_MOON: Ambiguous: Variable is undefined: MEAN or: Function not found: MEAN
% Execution halted at: ECLIPSE_MOON        23 /home/fabian/Downloads/eclipse_moon.pro
%                      $MAIN$          
GDL> 0:45 / 9:10
% ECLIPSE_MOON: Parser syntax error: unexpected token: 0
GDL>
```

I ran this same code on linux with IDL installed and it was perfectly fine.

It seems I have to install some more stuff. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it couldn't find a function called `MEAN`. Make sure it is in your !path and that you are calling it properly. When IDL (or GDL) runs a function or program, it searches all of the directories in the variable `!path` to find it. If it is found, IDL will load the function and continue compiling. In this case I expect that the function `ECLIPSE_MOON` calls `MEAN` on line 23. But `MEAN` (which is usually built in in IDL) is not found in GDL. So you need to make sure it can be found.

To check what your path, in a GDL session type `print,!path` and make sure the function `MEAN` is in one of those directories.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @FabianMenezes, I edited the answer to better answer your question. Does that help you?

Comment: @FabianMenezes, If this helped you, please select it as the correct answer.